# Microchip IS1678S Questions - wanting to implement SPP as simply as possible

Tags: bluetooth, microchip

I'm looking for a solution to implement Blutooth Classic SPP on a chipset. What I'd like is everything to be on an external chip, so I don't have to run any sort of Bluetooth stack on my STM32 which is my system processor.

The [IS1678S](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/IS1678) looks like it might do the trick, but I have recently been poorly advised by TI on this topic with one of their chips, so I am being a lot more careful before I present a potential solution. The datasheets/apps notes for this device are clearly not written by a native English speaker and some of the things are unclear (or at least are to me).

Has anyone used this device? Is it possible just to hook it up to your micro, tell it [the IS1678S] to go to SPP in Classic mode, pair it with am external bluetooth node and have it send raw data to and from your own micro to an external unit such as a laptop? The kind of thing you can do with things like the old Bluegiga BT modules such as the BT121 and older. I think the term cable replacement is sometimes used; I'm looking for a wireless UART basically.

The really important thing is that I don't need any sort of Bluetooth stack on my STM32.

Please note I cannot use a module on this application, this is why I'm looking at an SoC like this.

Comment: figure 2.8.1 (page 16) of the application note indicates that only status and UART functions are visible to the MCU ......... http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/IS1678S_ApplicationNote.pdf

Comment: Yes, but what does that mean? I appreciate to someone who understands this better this might be clear, but to me I am just not getting what that says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help anyone else in the future grappling with this, you can use the IS1678S exactly as I wish without any need for a host stack. I got this going with the BM78 module which uses the IS1678S. I had to change the RF channel to make it easy to connect up to my Linux laptop's rfcomm port, but that was easy with the UI tool.

Mictrochip have confirmed that no external stack at all is needed when switching from module to SoC, so this is a very good solution.